# How to create elements depending on data in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

looking at [sample](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data):

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
  .enter().append("div")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

cant help but wonder how to make append sensitive to provided data - say `do append and fill text` with some predicate say `if d == 8` othervise do not append?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The simplest way is to filter your array before calling `.data( ... )`:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
    .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42].filter(function(d){ return d < 10; }))
  .enter().append("div")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

will create a div only for 4 and 8.

Alternatively, you can filter your selection after binding your array to elements on the page to conditionally create children elements:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
  .enter().append("div")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
 .filter(function(d){ return d == 8; }).append("span")
    .text("Equal to 8")
```

Answer (score -1):

In your example, you want to add something depending on a condition or add nothing else. However, if you want to add something but it depends on a condition what you append, then you can use the fact that most values in *D3* can be passed by constants *and* functions. This also applies to the function `.append( ... )`.

So if you want to append something but the type of DOM node you want to append depends on a condition, you can use something like the following:

```js
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
        .enter().append((d) => document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
            d < 10 ? "rect" : "circle"))
            .text(function(d) { return d; });
```