# Append conditionally without filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, conditional-statements

I've seen many questions on this site asking how one can append an element to a selection depending on the data it would be bound to. ([Here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723916/how-to-create-elements-depending-on-data-in-d3), for example.) All of them seem to advocate filtering the data first to remove the items for which elements shouldn't be bound.

I can't do this because filtering out items in the data would change the indices of all elements afterward, and my code depends on the indices. I realized that I could create a tuple for each item, containing a datum and its original position, and then safely filter, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

**How can I append an element depending on the data to which it would be bound without filtering the data first?**

---

My situation specifically: I have a 2D array. Each child array is bound to a `<g>`, and for each element within each child array, a `<path>` is calculated and drawn. The `<path>`'s `transform` depends on the element's index in the child array.

For some elements within any given child array, I want no `<path>` to be drawn. I realize I could accomplish this without not appending a `<path>` (for example, by making the `<path>` entirely translucent), but I'm trying to cut down on the number of elements in the hierarchy.

Currently, I bind all the data to a `<path>`, then filter and remove certain `<path>`s depending on their data. This doesn't seem particularly efficient, though...

Comment: You could just remove the path after appending with `.filter().remove()`. Interested in hearing if there's a better way.

Comment: An even easier solution is keeping both arrays, the original one and the filtered one, using the filtered one to bind the data and the original one to the `transform`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado But that then requires finding the corresponding element in the original array for each element that's in the filtered array that gets bound—sounds intensive?

Comment: @DWal That's what I'm doing now. (Should have added that to the question).

Comment: This is tangential, but I'd make sure you're not optimizing prematurely here.  "Wanting to cut down on the number of elements in the hierarchy" doesn't seem like a very pressing concern, and the efficiency of a project that isn't done yet is 0.

Comment: @Brandon Good point, but my browser is often trying to render more than 1 million elements, which makes testing difficult, so it is a pressing concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163294/d3-append-conditionally-without-filtering#comment73401905_43163294), one possible solution is keeping two arrays, one for appending the elements (the filtered one) and one for referencing their indices (the original one). Is that approach intensive (regarding processor resources)? It depends on your actual code and case. Sometimes, a code that seems less performant can surprisingly perform better than one that is supposed to be faster (for instance, appending elements and removing them later... browsers are normally faster manipulating arrays and objects than manipulating actual DOM elements).

Anyway, here is *another* approach: create your new filtered data referencing the index of each element in the original data.

For instance, in the following snippet, I have this data set:

```
var originalData = [16, 18, 4, 17, 12, 2, 15, 13, 8, 19, 17, 3, 8];
```

We're gonna make a filtered array keeping only the values that are smaller than 10. But, before filtering, we'll create an object that holds the value and the original index:

```
var filteredData = originalData.map((d, i) => ({
    value: d,
    index: i
})).filter(e => e.value < 10);
```

Then, you just need to access `index` to know the original index.

Here is the demo, click the circles:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var originalData = [16, 18, 4, 17, 12, 2, 15, 13, 8, 19, 17, 3, 8];

var filteredData = originalData.map((d, i) => ({
  value: d,
  index: i
})).filter(e => e.value < 10);

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(filteredData)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 20)
  .attr("cy", 40)
  .attr("cx", (d, i) => 40 + 60 * i)
  .attr("fill", "teal")
  .attr("cursor", "pointer")
  .on("click", function(d) {
    console.log("My original index is " + d.index)
  })
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 20% !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```